# Select all data different second between two date times

Tags: mysql, datetime, between

I have a mysql table with data connected to date and time. Each row has data and a date, like this:

```
datetime               name
2009-06-25 10:00:00    jhon
2009-06-25 10:00:05    jack
2009-06-25 10:00:11    json
2009-06-25 10:00:15    jack
```

My problem is I need to get the rows different second date1 and date2 like this :

```
datetime               name     second
2009-06-25 10:00:00    jhon     0
2009-06-25 10:00:05    jack     5
2009-06-25 10:00:11    json     6
2009-06-25 10:00:15    jack     4
```

Thank you

Comment: Right, I'll remove the comment

Comment: use self join to get this

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are seeking is `LAG`, which is an available as an analytic function in many databases, though not in MySQL.  However, you can simulate this functionality using session variables.

```
SET @dt = (SELECT MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)) FROM yourTable);

SELECT t.datetime,
       t.name,
       t.curr_dt - t.lag_dt AS second
FROM
(
    SELECT @dt:=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) curr_dt,
           @dt lag_dt,
           datetime,
           name
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY datetime, name
) t
```

Comment: This is approach is pretty fast

Comment: @tim ..its showing seconds difference to zero in all rows ..not as per user expected ..http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a295e8/3

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal Session variables do not appear to be working in Fiddle.  You would need to test it in actual Workbench.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i did the same on my local ...but still same result

Answer (score 1):

You can find the nearest date and find the difference like below

```
select 
    datetime,
    name,
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(datetime, prev_date)) diff
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
        datetime,
        name,
        (select datetime from tbl t1 where t1.datetime<tbl.datetime order by  datetime desc limit 1) as prev_date
        FROM 
        `tbl`
      )tmp
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative to the answer I gave, and should be fine for reasonably sized data sets.

Answer (score 0):

The result is :

[SQL]SET @dt = (SELECT MIN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) FROM gps_trs_location);
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(datetime) FROM gps_trs_location)' at line 1

Comment: Sorry, typo, use this: `SET @dt = (SELECT MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)) FROM yourTable);`